# pylint painfully slow when using extension-pkg-whitelist=PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pylint

I'd like to set

```
[MASTER]
extension-pkg-whitelist=PyQt5
```

in `pylintrc` to avoid all those false positives.

Unfortunately, it makes pylint run much slower.

I'm using vim/syntastic to call pylint on each file write. Without this line, `pylint` runs in about 2-3 seconds. Not ideal but I can live with it. Using `extension-pkg-whitelist=PyQt5`, it takes about 15 seconds, which makes it practically unusable.

There is nothing else in `pylintrc`.

Is this a known issue? I couldn't find any reference to it.

Am I missing something in the config? Is there any workaround?

Comment: I switched from vim-syntastic to [vim ALE](https://github.com/w0rp/ale) so the calls to pylint/flake8 are not blocking anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem. As a workaround, for my own small project, instead of

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, etc, etc
```

I have used

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
```

Then the whitelisting directive is not needed.

Another workaround would be to not use the whitelisting directive and to disable that warning from pylint. But this has the unwanted side-effect of
hiding all those errors, even the real ones.

```
# pylint: disable=no-name-in-module
```